# c++ inheritance darray from array

Tags: c++

i do this in the education purpose.
 such is idea:
  i  have class Array.  I inheritance it in class Darray, and add necessary dimension

it likes so:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


  Array obj;
  obj.output();

 DArray obj2;
 obj2.output();

   return 0;
```

}

header

```
      class Array

       {
        public:
          int  *x,sizem;  //одно измерение, массив
                // можно объявить здесь как  **x , но это не то

      Array();
       ~Array();
   virtual  void output();
   };


   class DArray:public Array
 {
public:
 int **z;
  int sizen;
   DArray();
~DArray();
 virtual void output();
};
```

realisation.cpp

```
           Array::Array()
        {
        sizem=5;

        x=new int[sizem];

         for(int i=0;i<sizem;i++)
       x[i]=i;
         }

        Array::~Array()
     {
        delete []x;
       }


       void Array::output()
       {
       for(int i=0;i<sizem;cout<<x[i]<<" ",i++);
       cout<<"\n";
        }


           void DArray::output()
      { cout<<"\n";

       for(int i=0;i<sizem;i++)
         {   for(int j=0;j<sizen;j++)
               cout<<z[i][j]<<" ";
             cout<<"\n";
              }
              }       


        DArray::DArray()
           {
            int i;
           sizen=sizem;

           z=new int*[sizem];   // одно измерение уже есть, т.е. это одна строка


             for(i=1;i<sizem;i++)
               z[i]=new int[sizem];


            for(int i=1;i<sizem;i++)   // if i don't initialization  matrix, all'll 

          works right,compiles,and run, but AFAIK  when i allocate space dynamically,
         it must be intitializationed self by zeros, but it isn't particually equal
          zeroes, the fisrt two  column are equal  some random number, other 
       are equal zero.


             for(int j=0;j<sizen;j++)
               {
                z[i][j]=2;
                }

              *z=x;  // i've already array x , that was inheritanced, just point address
            }



                DArray::~DArray()
           {


          for(int i=1;i<sizem;i++)
           delete z[i];


           // yet one problem 
           // i can't delete  x  e.g. delete []x
         // but it should work! 

                 delete []z;
                   }
```

PS I works without errors, but i think there are memory leak, but can't catch up why

all tricks has been done in constructor, everything other is general stuff like output matrix/array.  that's why i think that problem is there

```
thanks you  mates!
```

but i don't understand yet one thing

```
          z=new int*[sizem];  

           for(i=1;i<sizem;i++)
          z[i]=new int[sizem];


       for(int i=1;i<sizem;i++)
      {
         for(int j=0;j<sizen;j++)

           cout<<z[i][j]<< " ";
           cout<<"\n";
       }
 as i think i have to receive here  ones zeros. byt i receive something like

          2532336 2532336 0 0 0 
          2532336 2532336 0 0 0 
          2532336 2532336 0 0 0 
          2532336 2532336 0 0 0
```

Why?

Comment: it was a joke, please ignore.

Comment: If you want help, then formatting your code improves your chances... Also providing a minimal sample to reproduce your problem is a good idea.

Comment: The simple idea of having a 2D array publicly inherit from a 1D one makes me shudder.

Comment: @shbk, StackOverflow is not a forum, but a site where you ask one question and receive several answers. You should mark one of those answers as correct answer. Please don't ask another question by editing existing question. This is not a forum. You should ask another question, and possibly put a link to previous one. This way you may receive several answers to new question, and these answers will not mix with existing answer to previous question. And then you should mark one of those new answers as the correct answer for your new question.

Comment: AProgrammer ,here it's insignificant for me, but i understand that to do inheritance with protected is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no memory leaks, but there is one mismatch between new and delete:

You're using `new[]` here:

```
for(i=1;i<sizem;i++)
    z[i]=new int[sizem];
```

but you're using `delete` (not `delete[]`) here:

```
for(int i=1;i<sizem;i++)
    delete z[i];
```

With that changed to `delete[] z[i];`, there are no warnings from valgrind:

```
==29235== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29235==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29235==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 160 bytes allocated
==29235== 
==29235== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

EDIT: regarding your second question, if you want the arrays to be initialized with zeroes, use

```
z[i] = new int[sizem](); // note the pair of parentheses
```

or just use vectors like everybody else.

Comment: mmm.. valgrid, it's interesting. i had change source code and 've tried to test it with valgrid as:  valgrid -ls -l myprogram. but i receive this:  ==20385== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20385==     in use at exit: 13,268 bytes in 29 blocks
==20385==   total heap usage: 251 allocs, 222 frees, 34,990 bytes allocated
 or should i use other options? what kind of ideas do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

z is a 2 dimensional array... you've allocated memory for each z[i] as an array.

So you need to use:

```
delete[] z[i];
```

Comment: He isn't allocating z[0] in DArray's ctor, only z[1] and up.

Answer (score 1):

I have extracted a minimal sample from your code.

```
Array::Array()
{   
    sizem=5;

    x = new int[sizem];
}

Array::~Array()
{
    delete[] x;
}

DArray::DArray()
{
    z = new int*[sizem];

    for(int i=1; i < sizem; i++)
         z[i]= new int[sizem];

    *z=x; // Wierd but ok
}

DArray::~DArray()
{
    for(int i=1;i<sizem;i++)
        delete z[i]; // Should be delete[] since elements were allocated through z[i] = new int[sizem];

    delete[] z;
}
```